# how to display image and other detail from the database using php

Tags: php, mysql

my db table
table name 'store'

```
id |  regno |  name  |  image
------------------------------
1  |  101   |  xxxxx |  myimage
```

Here i able to search the particular image from the db but i need to display all the details such as regno, name, and image in same form please any body help me

table.php

```
<form action ="table.php" method="post">
search :<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php

echo $search =$_POST['search'];
 ?>

<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#ffffff" border=1     bordercolor="#2696b8">
<tr>
<td align="center" width="45" height="45"><img src="image.php?reg=<?php echo $search?>">


</tr>

</table>
```

image.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databaseimage") or die(mysql_error());
$sql ="select * from store where reg= '".intval($_GET['reg'])."' ";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
header('Content-Type: image/png');
 echo mysql_result($result, 0);
if($result){
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  echo $row['image'];



}
else
{
  echo readfile('/your/path/error/image.png');
}?>
```

in this query i cannot able to display the image please help me

Comment: `echo $search =$_POST['search'];` is wrong. Should be `$search = $_POST['search'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
from store where reg= '
```

you have `regno` field, but not `reg`

Also, you don't need to set header content-type to image, as your request returns string, not an actual image.

Answer (score 0):

you can display image using

```
<img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
```

upload is your folder name where you uploading your images

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your query is returning any result set?
You should use the table field name 'regno' as stated in your database table to match the url query 'reg'

```
$sql ="select * from store where regno = '".intval($_GET['reg'])."' ";
```

instead of your original query with the invalid field name 'reg' to build your query

```
$sql ="select * from store where reg = '".intval($_GET['reg'])."' ";
```

Second,
Are you trying to display the image on a webpage?
You can simply do the following but remember your $row['image'] should include the absolute or relative path to the image file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action ="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
search :<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" name="submit" name="Search">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

    $s = $_REQUEST['search'];
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("databaseimage") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql ="select * from store where reg= '%".$s."%' ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count != 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          echo $row['image'].'<br>';
          echo $row['regno'].'<br>';
          echo $row['name'];
        }
    }
    else{
      echo 'Error Message';
    }
}
?>
```